# Undefined control sequence with table xcolor package

Tags: tables, packages, undefined

I'm trying to colour some cells in a table. I've read that I need to use the package [table]xcolor, but my file is not compiling when I insert that package, I get an undefined control sequence type of error, even without trying to colour any cells. My code is

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}

N & 2 & 3 \\

2 & MS & MS \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which does not compile, but if you comment the line `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, it does compile. The error I get is very long, it starts with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\CT@setup ->\@tempdimb \col@sep 
                                \@tempdimc \col@sep \def \CT@color {\global ...
l.7 \begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
...
```

Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any reason for using the obsolete `revtex4` class instead of `revtex4-1`?

Comment: No, and this already solved the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The `revtex4` class is incompatible with `colortbl`, because it redefines the `tabular` environment so `\col@sep` gets undefined. This is an important dimension register defined in the `array` package, which `colortbl` relies upon.

The class is, however, obsolete and remains for back compatibility. The `revtex4-1` class doesn't suffer from the problem.

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]% <------ Never just h!
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}

N & 2 & 3 \\

2 & MS & MS \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```